# How to do multiple join on same table and then join with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I want to do inner join on same table i.e `product_attributes` where I want `prod_value = gender` and `prod_attr=Male` and maingroup = Pants. It means, I want all the products where gender is male and it falls under Pants .I even want to print prodgroup and join `product_master` table where I need `prod_name`. How can I achieve this?

Table 1 : Product_attributes

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | prod_style | prod_attr | prod_value |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 0010       | gender    |       Male |
|  2 | 0010       | maingroup |      Pants |
|  3 | 0010       | prodgroup |  Pants_Abc |
|  4 | 0010       | Blue      |      color |
|  5 | 0011       | gender    |       Male |
|  6 | 0011       | maingroup |      Pants |
|  7 | 0011       | prodgroup |  Pants_Pqr |
|  8 | 0012       | gender    |     Female |
|  9 | 0012       | maingroup |      Pants |
| 10 | 0012       | prodgroup |      Pants |
| 11 | 0013       | gender    |     Female |
| 12 | 0013       | maingroup |    Jackets |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Table 2 :Product_master

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | prod_style | prod_name | 
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | 0010       | ABC       |
|  2 | 0011       | PQR       |
|  3 | 0012       | XYZ       |
|  4 | 0013       | LMN       |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

I have tried with this solution:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    product_master pm 
    INNER JOIN (select 
                    * 
                from 
                    product_attributes 
                where 
                    prod_value='prodgroup' 
                        and prod_style in(select 
                                                prod_style 
                                          from 
                                                product_attributes 
                                           where 
                                                prod_attr ='pants' 
                                                and prod_value='mainGroup' 
                                                and prod_style in(select 
                                                                        prod_style 
                                                                   from 
                                                                        product_attributes 
                                                                   where 
                                                                        prod_attr='Male'
                                                                  )
                                           )
                ) p ON pm.prod_style = p.prod_style  
ORDER By 
    prod_name
```

With my solution I am getting output but don't know whether its correct way of writing query.

Output using the above solution :

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| id        | prod_style | prod_name | prod_style  | prod_attr | prod_value|
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1        | 0010       | ABC       |0010         |Pants_Abc  |prodgroup  |
|  2        | 0011       | PQR       |0011         |Pants_Pqr  |prodgroup  |
|  3        | 0012       | XYZ       |0012         |Pants      |prodgroup  |
|  4        | 0013       | LMN       |0013         |skinny     |prodgroup  |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @piya would you explain what you want ? i'm working on it! (I want all the products where gender is male and it falls under Pants)

Comment: I have explained above . I want to get all products whose gender is male and maingroup is Pants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built this query:

```
DECLARE @Product_attributes TABLE
(
    id INT
    , prod_style VARCHAR(10)
    , prod_attr VARCHAR(10)
    , prod_value VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @Product_master TABLE
(
    ID INT
    , prod_style VARCHAR(10)
    , prod_name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @Product_attributes (id, prod_style, prod_attr, prod_value)
VALUES (1, '0010', 'gender','Male')
    , (2, '0010', 'maingroup','Pants')
    , (3, '0010', 'prodgroup', 'Pants_Abc')
    , (4, '0010', 'Blue', 'color')
    , (5, '0011', 'gender', 'Male')
    , (6, '0011', 'maingroup', 'Pants')
    , (7, '0011', 'prodgroup', 'Pants_Pqr')
    , (8, '0012', 'gender', 'Female')
    , (9, '0012', 'maingroup', 'Pants')
    , (10, '0012', 'prodgroup', 'Pants')
    , (11, '0013', 'gender', 'Female')
    , (12, '0013', 'maingroup', 'Jackets');

INSERT INTO @Product_master (id, prod_style, prod_name)
VALUES (1, '0010', 'ABC')
    , (2, '0011', 'PQR')
    , (3, '0012', 'XYZ')
    , (4, '0013', 'LMN');

SELECT PA1.id, PA1.prod_style, PM.prod_name, PA1.prod_attr, PA1.prod_value
FROM @Product_attributes AS PA1
INNER JOIN @Product_master AS PM
    ON PM.prod_style = PA1.prod_style
WHERE PA1.prod_attr = 'mainGroup'
    AND PA1.prod_value = 'Pants'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @Product_attributes AS PA2
        WHERE PA2.prod_style = PA1.prod_style
            AND PA2.prod_attr = 'gender'
            AND PA2.prod_value = 'Male'
        );
```

It checks if your product (based on `prod_style`) is for males and is pants. BOTH conditions must be met, but it has different output than yours, which is:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ prod_style ║ prod_name ║ prod_attr ║ prod_value ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  2 ║       0010 ║ ABC       ║ maingroup ║ Pants      ║
║  6 ║       0011 ║ PQR       ║ maingroup ║ Pants      ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Did I lose something in your logic? Please let me know.

Comment: It gives output on demo table which has 10-11 records, but original table which has more than 1,00,000 records , your query doesn't work.It shows loading..

Comment: Query is not executing.

Comment: Does it throw an error message? If not, review indexes.

Comment: Your query executed but it took a long time.

Comment: Does it bring correct results? If so, you need to review indexes or possible performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT  *
FROM    product_master pm
        JOIN ( SELECT   t1.*
               FROM     product_attributes t1
                        JOIN product_attributes t2 ON t1.prod_style = t2.prod_style
                                                      AND t2.prod_attr = 'gender'
                                                      AND t2.prod_value = 'male'
                        JOIN product_attributes t3 ON t1.prod_style = t3.prod_style
                                                      AND t3.prod_attr = 'maingroup'
                                                      AND t3.prod_value = 'Pants'
             ) pa ON pm.prod_style = pa.prod_style
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which puts every *other* attr on its own line:

```
select pm.prod_style, pm.prod_name, pa.prod_attr, pa.prod_value
from Product_attributes pa
join Product_attributes pa_m on pa.prod_style = pa_m.prod_style
    and pa_m.prod_attr = 'gender' and pa_m.prod_value = 'Male'
join Product_attributes pa_g on pa.prod_style = pa_m.prod_style
    and pa_g.prod_attr = 'maingroup' and pa_g.prod_value = 'Pants'
join Product_master pm on pm.prod_style = pa.prod_style
where pa.prod_attr not in ('gender', 'maingroup')
```

If you want to have one row per product, try this:

```
select pm.prod_style, pm.prod_name, group_concat(concat(pa.prod_attr, '=', pa.prod_value)) attrs
from Product_attributes pa
join Product_attributes pa_m on pa.prod_style = pa_m.prod_style
    and pa_m.prod_attr = 'gender' and pa_m.prod_value = 'Male'
join Product_attributes pa_g on pa.prod_style = pa_m.prod_style
    and pa_g.prod_attr = 'maingroup' and pa_g.prod_value = 'Pants'
join Product_master pm on pm.prod_style = pa.prod_style
where pa.prod_attr not in ('gender', 'maingroup')
group by 1, 2
```

which will produce output like

```
prod_style | prod_name | attrs
0010       | ABC       | color=Blue,size=Large
```